# How do I synchronize two branches in the same Git repository?

Tags: git, workflow, git-rebase, git-branch

Here's a common workflow hurdle I encounter often:

### *master* is our "stable" branch

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

### Create a module on a branch

```
$ git checkout -b foo
$ echo "hello" > world
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "init commit for foo module"
$ git checkout master
$ git merge foo
```

### Do work on master or other branches

Over the next couple weeks, more code will be committed to master directly and by other branches. The `foo` branch will go untouched for this time period.

### Resume work/make updates on the *foo* branch

```
$ git checkout foo
```

Oh no! *foo* is massively out of date! I understand *why*, but I **do** need *foo* back in sync.

### The question

How do I get the latest contents from the *master* branch?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**If you don't need the branch around:**

If you've merged foo back to master, "git branch -d foo" to kill the topic branch, and then "checkout -b foo" in the future when you need to hack on it again.

**If you do need the branch around:**

You can rebase your topic branch against the master branch:

```
git checkout foo
git rebase master
```

Or:

```
git rebase master foo
```

Comment: Adam, consider the scenario where I need to temporarily "pause" development on the `foo` branch while I make quick changes on a `bugfix` branch. `bugfix` will be merged into `master`, but then it should be sync'd with `foo` afterward, too. Does that make sense?

Comment: In that case I rebase foo against master: "git checkout foo && git rebase origin/master"

Comment: Adam, [`rebase`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) is *exactly* what I was looking for; far more appropriate than deleting/recreating the topic branch, too. If you update your answer to "git rebase master", I'll be happy to accept it. (please do not specify `origin/master`, as I'm not dealing with a remote)

Comment: additional useful tidbit: `git rebase master foo` is equivalent to `git checkout foo && git rebase master` :)

Comment: This is potentially harmful if you have already published branch `foo` out of your machine. Rebasing it on master will change the sha of the commits contained in the branch, so when you try to push your rebased version of `foo` they won't match what is in the server, and it will tell you that you cannot complete the push because it's not a fast-forward.

Comment: giorgiosironi: Exactly. `git rebase`  should always be done **after** committing your changes, but **before** pushing or merging your changes into a public branch.

Comment: This is really nice, but if someone added something to foo in between (like, a team member). Then it doesn't work or you discard their stuff even though you shouldn't.

Comment: Bumping in hopes someone will offer an answer that everyone agrees is correct. Neatness counts.

Answer (score 20):

Rebasing is the process of moving or combining a sequence of commits to a new base commit. Rebasing is most useful and easily visualized in the context of a feature branching workflow. The general process can be visualized as the following:

[image: Git Rebase visual explanation]

The example below combines git rebase with git merge to maintain a linear project history. This is a quick and easy way to ensure that your merges will be fast-forwarded.

```
# Start a new feature
git checkout -b new-feature master
# Edit files
git commit -a -m "Start developing a feature"
```

In the middle of our feature, we realize there’s a security hole in our project

```
# Create a hotfix branch based off of master
git checkout -b hotfix master
# Edit files
git commit -a -m "Fix security hole"
# Merge back into master
git checkout master
git merge hotfix
git branch -d hotfix
```

After merging the hotfix into master, we have a forked project history. Instead of a plain git merge, we’ll integrate the feature branch with a rebase to maintain a linear history:

```
git checkout new-feature
git rebase master
```

This moves new-feature to the tip of master, which lets us do a standard fast-forward merge from master:

```
git checkout master
git merge new-feature
```

Taken from [Atlassian Git Rebase Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase)

Comment: I wish you could have shown this pictorially as well.

Comment: @not2qubit you mean screenshots ? or images explaining what is being doing to the branches ?

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to combine changes from two branches (mine and yours) and to synchronize both branches for continued work. This seems to be working. Does anyone see a problem with it?

```
git checkout mine # make sure I'm on my branch
git commit -a     # commit changes
git push origin mine  
git checkout yours # switch to your branch
git pull origin yours # get changes you've committed & pushed
git checkout mine 
git merge yours # merge your changes into mine
git push origin mine 
git checkout yours 
git rebase mine # set your branch to the merged result
git push origin yours # push the merged result up to your branch on origin
git checkout mine # get back to my branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Adam answer is good one.

Additionally, for those who are using IntelliJ and need help regarding rebase and merge, here is a link of youtube video. This will help you to visually understand how rebase works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nftif2ynvdA